# Error in UseMethod("group_vars") : no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "factor"

Tags: r, error-handling, count, plyr

I am using the function `count()` from the package `plyr`. Since this morning I receive an error when running the following code:

```
Arrivaltime <- cut(Export_2019_2$Arrival,
                   breaks = c(6.3, 6.45, 7, 7.15, 7.3, 7.45, 8),
                   labels = c("6:30-6:45", "6:45-7:00", "7:00-7:15", "7:15-7:30", "7:30-7:45", "7:45-8:00"))
```

The error is:

> Error in UseMethod("group_vars") :
> no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "factor"

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your post is not complete...I don't see any `count` and `group_vars` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install packages dplyr and plyr in your library. Make sure that they are both ticked. Otherwise that error will keep occurring. I just had the same issue as well.

[image]

Comment: thank you - i didn't have the plyr package loaded, and once i loaded it, `count` worked as expected.